# Drawbacks of using integers as IDs in MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, types, uniqueidentifier

I make a "copy" of MySQL table in MongoDB for PHP application.
And I have **id** column which is *PRIMARY KEY*.
Should I store it in mongodb as:

```
['_id' => (string) $id]
```

or

```
['_id' => (int) $id]
```

or

```
['_id' => new \MongoId($id)]
```

or

```
['_id' => new \MongoId, 'id' => $id]
```

I don't plan on having more than one machine for mongodb or making a lot of queries by that ID alone.

What is the difference in using string, integer or ObjectId here?

Comment: Do you want to specify _particular_ id? If not, MongoDB auto-generates you an objectID upon insert and you don't need to specify it.

Comment: @jpaljasma I gonna store that id anyway. but should I use it as ObjectId or get ObjectId from mongodb. and should I cast to integer or string, does it matter for performance or indexing or whatever which I don't know yet about mongodb?

Comment: You cannot store a MySQL int column as a `MongoId` they simply do not match in specification

Comment: Okay, the main question. Are you inserting to this collection? If so, how? From MySQl, if the `id` is preset then I see no problem replacing the `_id` with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above options would work. I personally like to leave `_id` for mongodb to manage and so would go with the fourth option.

I would make an exception for the case where this collection could grow to a large size. In that case, I would go for the second option since that would consume the least space.